# Control creation of metagen files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, c++-cli, metadata

A C++/CLI project I maintain using VS2012 mysteriously stopped creating a .metagen file for one of its dll's for one build configuration. The metagen file is still created for other build configs. We use the metagen files so I need to build them for all configs.

I've tried searching project properties for differences between the broken build config and others, but saw nothing that seemed to have anything to do with metagen files. I've also searched online and found nothing useful about creating or suppressing creation of these files.

How do I turn metagen file creation back on for this dll in this build config?

Comment: Very obscure, had to do some digging to find out what it might be.  It is a build artifact file, used to support the General + Enable Managed Minimum Rebuild setting.  Check if it is still set to Yes for that project.  Or yank up the build verbosity to see what it decides.  Very unwise to take a dependency on it btw, Microsoft may drop or alter this any time.

Comment: Thanks Hans. In my project the option was called "Enable Managed Incremental Build" -- I'm assuming that's the option you meant. It was already set to yes for the broken config. I think I'll just take your advice and stop depending on these files downstream.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved that same problem when I understood that Visual studio was actually driving me to search at the wrong place. Indeed, my release build aborted and the first error message I saw repeated (eating all the error window) was unresolved symbols followed by indications of a missing metagen file...

All this was actually a consequence of a DLL link step failure much earlier in the build, that same DLL out of which the 'metagen' is possibly (automatically) extracted. So I advise you to go through your project dependencies in your solution and perform 'project only' builds step by step until you find the first failure. And best you look at the 'build ouput' panel to see the first error that arises instead of trusting the 'error' panel to present you with the root cause at the top.

In my case it was a silly mistake in a library directory path that entailed a subsequent DLL link failure, that entailed subsequent XAML unresolved members in that DLL namespace, that entailed plenty of missing metagen file errors...